# Drupal php file in theme

Tags: php, drupal, file, themes

Under the path "\sites\all\themes\fusion\mytheme\", I found that some php file called "taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php", "views-view-fields--product-brand-category--block-2.tpl.php"... will generate some specific content on specific page, how can I configure this php file to specific link/block or whatever?

Comment: Uhm, you basically just asked "how does the template engine in drupal work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it would be a bit long to explain what to do with regards to what each file does. You would need to play around a bit and see how it all works.

I would recommend that you check out:

http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6

and read up on how the theme system works for the Drupal version that you are using.

but for example the "taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php" would be used to change the output of content that you would visit for a taxonomy term that you created.

eg. mysite.com/taxonomy/term/ which might be mysite.com/cooking-books/italian-pizzas

and the "views-view-fields--product-brand-category--block-2.tpl.php" would be for theming the output to one of your views which is configured to output as a block...

I'm happy to answer any more of your questions

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to configure a specific file to fill the role for a specific theme (the files are picked by their file name for their purpose).

You should check out the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module (specifically the theme devel module), which can tell you what parts of the output are expected in specific files.  I'm not sure if the themer module is still in devel for 6.x, but if it isn't, try the devel_themer module.